# How to position text in a matplotlib plot without mentioning any coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My plot is very dynamic and the function generating the plot have inputs that makes the plots scale vary. I need to position text outside the plot and do not want to provide any coordinates.

I am using the ax.text() function, with horizontal and vertical alignment. Now am using the maximum and minimum limits of the axis dividing it by the 4 times of the number of  ticks to find the x-cordinate to place the text. But as the scale of the plot varies the position gets shifted. Thats what I am trying to fix.

```
ax.text(
                    date_max+xaxis_shift,
                    thresh + 0.01 * y_range,
                    "Trendline surpasses threshold: " + x_cross.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    {"color": "r", "fontsize": 10},
                    ha="right",
                    va="bottom",
                    rotation="vertical",
                )
```

Comment: Do you mean relative positions? Something like "on top outside the plot" or "top left outside plot"? Can you provide us a minimal working example please.

Comment: Yes outside right side.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit], and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only plotting a single axes per figure, you may want to use [`figtext`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html) instead of `text`; that way you can hard-code figure coordinates and don't have to think about data coordinates.